# Canvas clearing cards

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas, onclick

When I click on a card element, I want it to clear the canvas and redraw everything except for the card that was clicked on.

The problem is, clicks on some positions clear more than one card, and i I don't know how to fix it. I have been trying to fix it but so far haven't been successful.

```
let elem = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = elem.getContext("2d"),
elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
let drawHelper = {
   pintarImagenes: function() {
         imagenes.forEach(function(image){
           drawHelper.pintarImagen(image);
         });
   },
   pintarImagen: function(image) {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.drawImage(image.image, image.x, image.y);
     ctx.clip();
     ctx.restore();
   }
};
let distancias =[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360, 390, 410, 440, 470, 510, 540, 570, 600, 630, 660, 690, 720, 750, 780, 810, 840, 870, 900];
let imagenes = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
  imagenes.push({
    x: (30*i),
    x1:((30*i)+270),
    y: 20,
    y1: 545,
    image: new Image()
  });
  imagenes[i].image.src = 'image.png';
  imagenes[i].image.onload = drawHelper.pintarImagenes;
}
elem.addEventListener('click', function onClickCanvas(event){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
      let i = 0;
      let newImagesArray = [];
      imagenes.forEach(function(image = distancias[i]){
        if( image.x <= event.clientX
          && image.y <= event.clientY
          && image.x1 >= event.clientX
          && image.y1 >= event.clientY){
            console.log(i);
          } else {
            newImagesArray.push(image);
          }
          i++;
        });
        imagenes = newImagesArray;
        drawHelper.pintarImagenes();
      });
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Raya082/pen/XWbpGKY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- The image width is larger than 270, so change `x1:((30*i)+270)` to `x1:((30*i)+340)`
- The cursor position given by `clientX` and `clientY` is not relative to the `canvas` element, so use `event.clientX - elem.offsetLeft` and `event.clientY - elem.offsetTop` to get to the right *x, y* coordinates.
- As you have overlapping cards, your condition will often match more than one card. In reality you only want to match the *rightmost* of those candidates, since the overlapping happens from left to right, which is also the order of the `imagenes` array. As you only need at the most one match, you can better use `findIndex` instead of `forEach`: find the first card that comes *after* the cursor's X-coordinate, and remove the card that precedes that card.

Here is the corrected code for dealing with the latter two points:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function onClickCanvas(event){
    let x = event.clientX - elem.offsetLeft;
    let y = event.clientY - elem.offsetTop;
    let i = imagenes.findIndex(image => image.x > event.clientX);
    if (i == -1) i = imagenes.length;
    i--;
    if (i >= 0) {
        let image = imagenes[i];
        if (image.x <= x && image.y <= y && image.x1 >= x && image.y1 >= y) {
           imagenes.splice(i, 1);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        drawHelper.pintarImagenes();
    }
});
```